# Standard parity-check matrices - how to construct them from a non standard one?

Tags: information-theory, coding-theory

I am working with LDPC codes, and I would need to guess the value of the standard parity-check matrix ($H_{sys}$) corresponding to my non-standard one ($H$) so as to deduce the value of the code's generator matrix $G$. These two matrices -$H$ and $G$- are of dimensions $(n-k,n)$ and $(k,n)$, respectively.

I guess that this standard form $H_{sys} = [I|A]$, where $I$ is the identity matrix, of dimension $k$ must exist for any $H$? As $H$ is a binary matrix, it would be needed to perform Gauss-Jordan elimination over GF(2) on it to calculate $H_{sys}$. However I get as a result some null rows, which cannot be at all, as these would be removable and the dimension of both $H$ and $H_{sys}$ would no longer be the same.

I am supposed to do this with large matrices so I must do it programatically (with Matlab). Any guidance from your side?

Many thanks in advance, and best regards!

Comment: By "standard" you mean "systematic" ?

Comment: Exactly @leonbloy. I thought it was the same

Comment: This wouldn't be about the LDPC codes in the  DVB-standard by any chance?

Comment: Nice guess @JyrkiLahtonen! Exactly, it is for my Master Thesis.

Comment: In that case I strongly advice you to consult the Blue Book. Due to the staircase shape of the check matrix it is much more efficient to use the  process described there for systematic encoding. Much less computation! Like a dozen bit operations per check bit as opposed to thousands what you may get with a "standard" generator matrix. I looked at this in some detail in 2008 when I worked for Nokia (read: I implemented this for testing/verification).

Comment: Hmm. IIRC the parity check matrices for DVB-S2/T2/NGH LDPC-codes had full rank. Now I'm slightly worried. May be this is an upgrade from the standard from 2008? Anyway, I still suspect that there might be a built in short cut.

Comment: Please don't worry! I am not exactly using the ones provided by the standard, but creating my own SC-LDPC-based ones and later comparing the results with the usual LDPC ones.

Comment: Ah! I see. Good luck!

Comment: As long as you are careful not to create short cycles and/or trapping sets I don't think the extra checks matter (I have tried something similar). But, to "sell" your code, you shouldn't ignore the practical aspect of ease of encoding without a generator matrix. If you have access to the DVB-standard, look at a section titled *Inner coding* (in my copy it is section 6.1.2, but that copy was from a draft era).

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track. Given $H=[A \mid B]$ you want to transform it, by Gaussian elimination to the systematic form, $H_s = [I \mid P']$
For this to work, you need $H$ to be full rank, that is, that its rows are linearly independent. If this is not so, then some of the rows of $H$ (which correspond to the parity equations) are redundant: then, [remove them](http://www.ldpc-codes.com/faq.html).

Comment: A just in case warning to the OP: You can remove the extra rows for the purposes of finding the generator matrix, but for heaven's sake don't remove them when decoding! The belief propagation may be detrimentally affected. Mind you, the LDPC codes I have seen (not too many I'm afraid) often come with an encoding algorithm. This is because the check matrix often has some special form that allows a short cut. That is just as well, because both $n$ and $k$ tend to be quite large (tens of thousands?) and using a non low-density generator matrix is then more than a bit kludgy..

Comment: Just one question: in case you come from constructing your original parity check matrix from a certain degree distribution, wouldn't this last be affected by this removal of redundant rows? (I don't know if I explained myself correctly) I would need to first make my parity check matrix systematic to then obtain its corresponding generator matrix, and last of it perform the decoding process. I don't see whether that was what you were meaning @JyrkiLahtonen. I am relatively new with LDPC coding...

Comment: @MisterTellini  "and last of it perform the decoding process"  No.no. As aptly pointed out by JyrkiLahtone, all this is only for encoding, the decoding is kept intact. If we do $H \to H_s \to G_s$ (where the systematic $H_s$ has perhaps less rows than $H$), the generator matrix $G$ generates a code for which both $H$ and $H_s$ are valid parity check matrices (in all cases the rows of $H,H_s$ are orthogonal to the rows of $G$, which is what matters - for being a valid parity check matrix. But , for LDPC decoding, $H$ is good and $H_s$ is not.

Comment: @leonbloy @Jyrki So let me put you an example to see if I got it right. I generated a matrix of dim $(17391x20460)$ whose rank is $17121$. Therefore some of its rows are redundant and I can wipe them out to create my gen matrix $G_s$. Would this matrix still be of dim $([20460 - 17391]x20460), (k x N)$ and obtainable (don't know if this question is proper here, sorry in advance if it's not) through `gen2par` command in Matlab? I'd later need to puncture this code to reach different rates -that is the main reason I want to make it systematic- and don't know if this would affect it somehow...

Comment: Can't help with Matlab, sorry.

Comment: @leonbloy Found a simpler example. Suppose that I have messages of length $k = 50$ and I want to use a rate $0.5$ code. Then my resulting parity check matrix (from both row and degree distribution) would be of dimension $50 \times 100$. In this case I have $8$ linear dependent rows, so after I remove them and make $H$ systematic its dimension is of $(42 \times 100)$. If I calculate the generator matrix $Gs$ from it, its dimension will be of $(58 \times 100)$. How can I encode my message then if it was of dimension $(1 \times 100)$?

Comment: @MisterTellini That is a rate $0.58$ code, because you have room for 58 payload bits within a block of 100. The extra dependent parity checks, while may help BP-decoding, won't affect the code rate.

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen What I have done so far is, from a given rate, optimize over a range of degree distributions to get the one with the best threshold. Then, from that distribution, I have used MacKay Algorithm to build up the corresponding (non-systematic) parity check matrix that is not regular. There is where I come from. So I don't know how can I get a different rate coming from a degree distribution optimized for a given one.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with MacKay algorithm. I came to coding theory from the algebra side, and those stochastic things are a bit difficult to me :-). So  MacKay doesn't give you control of the rank? The rank is automatic with a staircase structure (but it may force a bad degree distribution on you). Have you compared with other standardize LDPC-codes how they do this? Say, those specified for MediaFlo?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60328/discussion-between-mistertellini-and-jyrki-lahtonen).

Comment: Hello! What I finally did was to increase the codeword length so as to reduce the gap between the design rate and my new rate as much as I could. That might be the simplest solution...